# Alternatives for Cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin

Are there any command-line interface for Microsoft Windows other than cygwin. Currently, I am using cygwin but there are some commands that do not work as they are supposed to work on linux

Comment: which commands do not work?

Comment: -1 | For you did not even care to specify any command which allegedly does not work.

Comment: it's a reasonable question; cygwin is not an OS, so there are obvious (and not-so-obvious) differences, as anyone who has used both knows ( https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html ). WSL is an alternative, but has its own issues ( https://superuser.com/questions/1119886/is-there-reason-to-use-cygwin-over-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10 ) or git bash for windows, which is limited, but useful of course for git ( https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway and https://superuser.com/questions/1191805/can-git-bash-and-cygwin-shell-do-the-same-things )

Answer (score 5):

I use [Swan](http://www.starlig.ht/) which *is* Cygwin, but is much more organised and behaves just like a Linux OS.

Comment: By "_behaves just like a Linux OS_" do you mean "_has a GUI just like a Linux OS_"? From the outside I can't see that Swan offers anything much more than that, and personally I don't really have a problem with Cygwin's command-line behaviour. Not complaining, just curious.

Comment: @roaima Swan installs it self like a Linux System in C:\ProgramData\Swan which is mounted as root and the the users HOME folder is mounted at $USERNAME/AppData/Swan which cannot be accessed by other users (unless it's an admin) which is a really neat feature, almost like a Linux OS, I really recommend that you try Swan for yourself, it's not that big of a install

Comment: +1 for swan. As a long time cygwin user (but my main OS is Unix/Linux), I appreciate that swan has a decent command-line interface to the cygwin package manager (and decent terminal, albeit as always w/ cygwin-on-windows, some gotchas & differences to work-around.) Kind of like babun used to do, before it was seemingly abandoned.

Comment: Swan appears to be dead. The website cannot be reached and there haven't been any commits to the project for the last eight years.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) instead; that solves a number of Cygwin’s issues.

Comment: The subsystem has its own set of problems but is great for command line only applications, I feel that [Swan](http://www.starlig.ht/) although the same Cygwin under the hood, is much better.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not content with Cygwin, you can try one of the following. These are more or less based on cygwin, but the behaviour and features are a bit different:

- **[MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)**. *"At its core is an independent rewrite of MSYS, based on
  modern Cygwin (POSIX compatibility layer) and MinGW-w64 with the aim
  of better interoperability with native Windows software. It provides
  a bash shell, Autotools, revision control systems and the like for
  building native Windows applications using MinGW-w64 toolchains."* -
  Unlike cygwin, this has built-in package manager pacman (like Arch Linux)
- **[Git bash for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)** - It supports rather basic commands, but it
  might be enough for you.
- **[MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)** - basically an interface for Cygwin, but has it's own
  package manager and it's quite well integrated with Windows shell. It comes with X server, tabbed SSH and other tools. Full version is paid, but you can do quite many things with the basic version.